# Defining type for an InfiniteScroll react component with typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to create a `InfiniteScroll` component to use it in this way:

```js
import { getData } from 'api';
import { InfiniteScroll } from 'components';

export const App = () => (
  <InfiniteScroll fetcher={page => getData({page})}>
    {({items}) => items.map(item => <p key={item.id}>{item.name}</p>)}
  </InfiniteScroll>
);
```

and `getData` is a function that get page as its parameter and returns a Promise like this:

```js
type Data = {
  id: number;
  name: string;
};

function getData(args: { page: number }): Promise<Data[]> {
  // ...
}
```

Now my question is how can I define type for my `InfiniteScroll` component to set type for its render prop function automatically?

Actually I want `items` in the render props retrieve its type from `Data[]` that is return value of the Promise used in `fetcher` prop

I added this codesandbox for working on it:
https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-resonance-lj09h?file=/src/InfiniteScroll.tsx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we could see the `InfiniteScroll` component code, we could probably help you better but essentially, you have to do something like below.

```
interface Props<T> {
  fetcher: (page: number) => Promise<T[]>;
  children: (data: T[]) =>  JSX.Element;
}

export const InfiniteScroll = <T extends unknown>({
  fetcher,
  children
}: Props<T>) => {
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const [data, setData] = useState<T[] | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetcher(page).then((res) => {
      setData(res);
    });
  }, [page]);

 if (!data) return (
    <p> loading... </p>
  )
  return (children(data))
};
```

App.tsx:

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <InfiniteScroll fetcher={(page: number) => getData(page)}>
        {(items) => (<>
           {(items.map((item, 
            index) => <p key={index}> {item.name} </p> ))} 
         </>)}
      </InfiniteScroll>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But unfortunately its not working. I created a simple codesandbox for it. you can see if you hover over `items` its type shows `unknown[]`

Comment: great! It's working now. The magic is in App.tsx:4 where you declare page type explicitly to number. If you remove it, everything break. Do you know why this happens?

Comment: @Omid, I'm not really sure tbh. I guess it has something to do with `implicit any` and inner workings of `typescript` and `react`. generally writing generic typescript components in react isn't _fun_.